# MongoDB performance degradation

Tags: mongodb, performance

I'm running performance tests on some Java code that sits on top of a local docker-compose/MongoDB default image:

```yaml
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
```

Overall throughput degrades by approximately 3-6% every time I run the test, and everything points at Mongo being the culprit. At the start of the test I by drop documents from the database, so it's not a size thing. I also recreate the other containers, Wiremock, Zookeeper and AMQ, just to make sure it has nothing to do with them. If I wait for a couple of hours, performance is high again. Restarting the computer does not help, and of course it also doesn't help to just `docker stop+start`.

To me it seems like some kind of Mongo housekeeping sometimes happens, which frees up resources or disk cache? Anybody seen this before? If my assumption is correct, how can I force run the housekeeping? If not: what else could it be? (I would prefer to not recreate the database every time, although that's my last resort.)

Comment: You say that you start your tests with a clear database each time. What you do next? Do you write documents there? What is an approximate total amount of data in the db?

Comment: I clear some documents, then the test create14k documents and update another 30k or so in three different collections. The total size is about 1GB.

Comment: Using `mongorestore` I was able to circumvent the problem. Tried the `compact` command, but that also didn't help.